# Real Canonical Form of Arbitrary Size Matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have been searching the site and the *Mathematica* documentation, but have not found anything regarding this.

If we find the Jordan Form of the following matrix, we get complex values, but I would like to find the real canonical form (all values in the Jordan matrix are real).

```
 JordanDecomposition[{{3, -2}, {1, 1}}]
```

Using this decomposition (or `MatrixExp`), we are able to find the exponential, $e^{t A}$, of this matrix.

For this particular problem, we find the real canonical form as:

$$P = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$J_R = P^{-1} A P  = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
 -1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

We can then use this real variant to find the matrix exponential as:

$$e^{t A} = P e^{t J_R} P^{-1}$$

You can see another $2\times 2$ and a $3\times3$ example [*here*](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~jmckinno/Math225/Week11/Lecture3s.pdf) and here is a [*larger example*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207397/real-jordan-form-to-complex-jordan-form-then-compute-p-matrix).

Is *Mathematica* able to find the Real Canonical Form for an arbitrarily sized matrix (hopefully I am just missing something basic)?

**Update**

These [*notes*](http://www.numbertheory.org/courses/MP274/realjord.pdf) provide an algorithmic type approach.